# How to concatenate an integer variable to a string literal

Tags: c++, string

I want to concatenate an int variable to a string literal.String literal is a path.
This is the code

```
bitmap.Save(L"D:\\screen.jpeg", &clsid);
```

In this code,i would like to add int variable after screen.I have tried this

```
bitmap.Save(L"D:\\screen"+k+L".jpeg", &clsid);// where k is the integer variable.
```

Unfortunately, it did not worked for me.The error was

```
"error C2110: '+' : cannot add two pointers"
```

Comment: Use [`std::wistringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) to build the filename.

Comment: But you *can* add an int to a pointer, including the pointer to which a wide string literal (which is an array of const `wchar_t`)  decays. The result is another pointer though; there is no "int.ToString() magic" as e.g. in C# which appends a string representation of the int.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler complains, because `L"D:\\screen.jpeg"` is of type `wchar[]` and `k` is int (probably).
The simplest way would be to explicitely convert `int` to `wstring` (or `string`) using `std::to_wstring` (or `std::to_string`) method.

```
bitmap.Save((L"D:\\screen" + std::to_wstring(k) + L".jpeg").c_str(), &clsid);
```

Comment: Error was this........ 'Gdiplus::Status Gdiplus::Image::Save(const WCHAR *,const CLSID *,const Gdiplus::EncoderParameters *)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>' to 'const WCHAR *'.........

Comment: I think no conversion operator available that can perform this operation in my solution..not sure..i think so

Comment: @GreeshmaPanicker I edited my answer to reflect that state, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in C++11, use [`std::to_wstring`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_wstring).

```
bitmap.Save(L"D:\\screen" + std::to_wstring(k) + L".jpeg", &clsid);
```

If you're not in C++11 unfortunately, you can use [`std::wstringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream).

```
std::wstringstream strm;
strm << L"D:\\screen" << k << L".jpeg";
bitmap.Save(strm.str());
```

Comment: @GreeshmaPanicker Maybe you forgot to use `c_str()` if `Save()` accepts `const char *`. Be familar with C++...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `std::wstring`, but you need to call `.c_str()` in order to use it with API that expect `wchar_t *`.

```
std::wstring filename = L"D:\\screen" + std::to_wstring(k) + L".jpeg";
bitmap.Save(filename.c_str(), &clsid);
```